# Use keys of Object as value for interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this

```
const foo = {
    "bar": "a",
    "foobar": "b"
}
```

How would I use the keys of the object `foo` as allowed values for a prop in an interface

```
interface SomeInteface {
    a: // only "bar" and "foobar" as strings allowed
}
```

I tried

```
interface SomeInteface {
    a: keyof foo
}
```

but that gave me

> 'foo' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof foo'?

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell typescript that it should make a type out of `foo`:

```
interface SomeInteface {
    a: keyof typeof foo
}
```